Power BI DAX doesn't return value selecting from slicer
This is indigestible problem I have been going through, actually I am trying to list those team who played against the another team. So, when I am manually entering team name in DAX calculation it is showing me desire output but as I am trying to make it dynamic means getting value from SELECTEDVALUE() then it doesn't showing anything. Below, I have mentioned the code, kindly provide me the solution why it is happening like this?
TeamAgainstScore = 
VAR ctry = "CAN" | **SELECTEDVALUE(Matches[Country])**
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Mathces Details'[Score]),
    FILTER(
        'Mathces Details',
        'Mathces Details'[Country] <> ctry &&
        (
            'Mathces Details'[match_id] IN
            CALCULATETABLE(
                VALUES('Mathces Details'[match_id]), 
                'Mathces Details'[Country] = ctry
            )
            ||
            SEARCH(ctry, 'Mathces Details'[match_id], 1, 0) > 0
        )
    )
)


Is TeamAgainstScore a measure or a calculated column?

It’s a measure. Even I am tried with creating table but there also SELECTEDVALUE did not work

Are you absolutely sure it's a measure? There is a big difference between measures and calculated columns. It looks to me like you created a calculated column, not a measure, and that's why it's not working.

No bro, It is a measure. Actually when I am passing manual CAN it showing the team who played against him. But as I am trying to get from SELECTEDVALUE it showing me nothing.

can you share a pbix file?

Is SELECTEDVALUE() returning a single value? It will be blank if there are more than one result.

Yes, I am selecting only one country from the slicer, for instance Canada then chart should show me the score of the country played against him. Although I am attaching my .pbix file @RADO [link] (https://1drv.ms/u/c/7bfcf83070416e9c/EUvslKuZa29LjjV-J3LpzqMBhCnCRE9LTWHV8lcjLrBBjQ?e=QErNrr) . I would appreciate if you have other solution.
